# Rails hash TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, type-conversion

I have the following hash, `@example_set` that I want to get and store data from.

```
{"Example1"=>{:campaign=>"Example1", :impressions=>12, :conversions=>1, :clicks=>14, 
"Example2"=>{:campaign=>"Example2", :impressions=>4042, :conversions=>2, :clicks=>11}}
```

I want to do the following to combine the total conversions but am running into a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.

```
@totals = 0
@example_set.each do |report|
   @totals += report[:conversions]
end
```

Ideally this would set `@totals` to `3`

I am new to rails so any additional detail and instruction would be much appreciated (especially if there is a better way to do this.. which I assume there is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate over values of that map, I think.

`@example_set.values.each`

Comment: Wow.. that was simple.. other than that am I approaching this the wrong way?